# detaching editor view

Tags: editor, detach

I'm working with aptana for a couple of weeks now. I have multiple displays (4) 
i like to edit in my mmiddle screen and have the views like projects outline, problems, etc on an other display. So far so good. But, to have an automatically updated preview I have to open to windows in the first I open the html file and click the preview button, after that I drag the file to the second window. Works very good. Wouldn't it be easy to detach the editor view like the app,outline and problem view? 
John